# NSAttributedString error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, nsmutableattributedstring

```
class Markdown: NSObject {

  func markdownString(stringForVideoDescription:NSString) ->   NSMutableAttributedString {
    var options = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType]

    var error:NSError?

    var markdown:NSString = stringForVideoDescription
    var html:NSString = MMMarkdown.HTMLStringWithMarkdown(markdown, error: &error)

    var markdownAttributedString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: html.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF32StringEncoding)!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil, error: &error)!

    if let font: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Marion-Regular", size: 14) {
      markdownAttributedString.addAttributes([NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName], range: NSMakeRange(0, markdownAttributedString.length))
    }

    print(html) // used to see that markdown is in fact working

    return markdownAttributedString
  }
}
```

this code worked before in until Swift changes that now show error on line:

```
var markdownAttributedString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: html.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF32StringEncoding)!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil, error: &error)!
```

Error is "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

I see others with issue and solutions, but these didn't work for me. I tried:

```
var markdownAttributedString: [NSMutableAttributedString: NSObject]...
```

I tried exchanged out the error in that line with just NSError so that no longer an optional. I tried removing ! in various places as that was suggestions in other posts. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? Since Swift 2.2, you don't put anymore the `(NS)Error` parameter. Swift handle Error, with a try/catch: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html
So it won't know that method.

Comment: I'm using 2.2. I haven't yet worked with the try/catch yet.